Why is the printf statement for number of pennies printing off when casting the double variable to an int?
I have a trivial program that I wrote to calculate the number of quarters, dimes, nickels, and pennies in an amount entered in (less than $1.00).
When I enter in specific amounts (.57 as an example) the number of pennies is printed incorrectly. In testing, the math on the doubles to calculate the pennies is correct and prints out correctly but when casting it to an int, it prints out incorrectly and I can't figure out exactly why.
I absolutely understand that there can be round off errors with decimal division etc. but in the case of an input of .57 it is doing the division part properly (0.02 / 0.01) = 2.00000 but the casting of that amount stored in the variable is failing. I've tried it by coding constant double amounts of 0.02 / 0.01 and then casting to an int and that seems to work properly so I'm struggling to figure out why it's failing when I work with the variable instead.
Example
As an example, when i enter it .57 for the change amount, the math on the doubles to calculate the pennies prints out amount_left as 2.000000 but when i then cast the variable to an int and assign that to the number of pennies variable like this:
number_of_pennies = (int)amount_left;

the number of pennies variable prints out Pennies: 1 instead of the expected 2.
Here is the full program code.
Full Code
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    char line[100], character_eater[100];
    int number_read_status, number_of_quarters, number_of_dimes,
        number_of_nickels, number_of_pennies;
    double amount_entered_in, amount_left;

    printf("Enter in an amount less than $1.00 to be converted to quarters, dimes, nickels, and pennies in format '.##': ");
    fgets(line, sizeof(line), stdin);
    number_read_status = sscanf(line, "%lf", &amount_entered_in);

    /* store all non-numeric characters entered in for input validation */
    sscanf(line, "%s", &character_eater);

    /* input validation */
    while(number_read_status != 1 || amount_entered_in > .99) {
        printf("\nA valid amount was not entered in. The amount must be less than $1.00 in format '.##'. Please try again.\n");
        printf("Enter in an amount less than $1.00 to be converted to quarters, dimes, nickels, and pennies: ");
        fgets(line, sizeof(line), stdin);
        number_read_status = sscanf(line, "%lf", &amount_entered_in);
        sscanf(line, "%s", &character_eater);
    }

    /* calculate change in quarters, dimes, nickels, and pennies */
    number_of_quarters = (amount_entered_in / .25);
    amount_left = amount_entered_in - number_of_quarters * .25;
    number_of_dimes = (amount_left / .10);
    amount_left -= number_of_dimes * .10;
    number_of_nickels = (amount_left / .05);
    amount_left = (amount_left - number_of_nickels * .05);
    amount_left = (amount_left / .01);
    printf("Amount left: %lf", amount_left); /* this prints out 2.000000 */
    number_of_pennies = (int)amount_left;

    /* print out change in quarters, dimes, nickels, and pennies */
    printf("\nThe number of quarters, dimes, nickels, and pennies equivalent to %lf are as follows:\n", amount_entered_in);
    printf("\tQuarters: %d\n", number_of_quarters);
    printf("\tDimes: %d\n", number_of_dimes);
    printf("\tNickels: %d\n", number_of_nickels);
    printf("\tPennies: %d\n", number_of_pennies); /* prints out wrong sometimes -- .57 for example */
    return(0);
}


Printf rounds to nearest, but casting to int always rounds down. So this is consistent with the answer having been something like 0.01999999.  As to why this is,  see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken

It looks to me (via print debugging of the double arithmetic prior to the casting operation) that the value is coming out as 2.000000 when I enter in input of .57 but then after the int cast it is printing out as 1. That's part of the reason I'm confused. It would seem like in this case that it would truncate down to 2 as an int and not 1.

There must be a duplicate for "Why is it not a good idea to use float for currency?"....

I'm using double in this -- unless I'm wrong or it's similar but my understanding was that double was more accurate. Are they about the same for currency? My aim from this question is to try to understand what's going on in this very particular case so that I have a better understanding of the language/what's happening. I can certainly re-write it to avoid what is happening here but would like to try to understand the nuances of why it works hardcoded and why it's rounding down from 2.00000 (via print debugging) all the way to 1 as an int cast.

@ManofManyTigers More values, yes, but more accurate, no.

Improving on @NateEldredge's response: "... but casting to int always rounds toward zero" The difference between accuracy and precision is subtle but significant.

Again, a number like 1.999999993 (count the digits!) would print as 2.000000 to six decimals, but since it is in fact less than 2, it still casts to int as 1. Don't use floating point at all for currency; instead, use integer variables that track the total number of cents. So $3.24 should be the integer 324.

OP's code is suffering from truncation issues that convert a floating point number like x.9999 to an int x rather than int x + 1.
Instead, after reading in the dollar amount of money as a double, round and convert to an integer type base unit of currency like cents.
number_read_status = sscanf(line, "%lf", &amount_entered_in);
if (number_read_status != 1) {
  Handle_Bad_input();
}
long long amount_cents = llround(amount_entered_in * 100.0);

Perform the rest of code using integer type objects like amount_cents, rather than floating point math.

Pedantically I would use long long amount_cents = llroundl(amount_entered_in * 100.0L); for potentially slightly better rounding in edge cases.

Tip: rather than debug floating point issues with printf("Amount left: %lf", amount_left);, use %g with sufficient precision to see issues.
printf("Amount left: %.*g", DBL_DECIMAL_DIG, amount_left);

... or if comfortable with hex output, use %a
printf("Amount left: %a", amount_left);


C2X plans to offer an optional decimal floating point, which is an elegant solution for the near future.

In the case of .57, it looks like amount_left is a double representing a value that is less-than 2.0 (e.g 1.9998). In this case, when case to int,
number_of_pennies = (int)amount_left;
the number is rounded down to 1.
You can resolving this by including math.h, and adding the line
amount_left = ceil(amount_left);

prior to the final cast.
See How to Convert double to int in C?

Switching to ceil will give wrong results when the answer happens to come out as 2.0000001. The correct fix is not to use floating point at all.

I see. Pretty sure i get it -- the printf() function rounds to the nearest digit (from let's say 1.99999993 or so) so it prints out 2.000000 and then when I cast, it gets truncated, printing out to 1. I think this explains what I was looking for -- which was to understand why print and then the print of the cast were different. I've re-written the code to use int fully instead and re-worked the input validation. Thanks for the explanation -- wasn't aware printf rounded to the nearest number while the variable stored a different value.
